# SSRS Data Feed (atomsvc file) for a Pivot Table in Excel - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a Data Feed file from SSRS (2016) that I am using as an External Data source for an Excel Pivot Table.   This works and data is returned to the Excel file to pivot. When the SSRS report has columns of type Text, Date or Integer, there are no problems.  As soon as a column type Numeric(x,y) is added to the report, the refresh of the data in Excel fails with a Type Mismatch error.  No further information is available.  In SQL when converted to INT the column pulls to excel.  The error is returned for Type NUMEIC, DECIMAL, FLOAT, REAL.  I have tried multiple regional setting options as I suspect the decimal separator.  No success.

What options are there to control decimal data from the SSRS data feed to get refreshable data into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CAST or CONVERT function in your SQL query to convert the numeric columns to a suitable data type like INT or DECIMAL.

Comment: Hi Steven - I can add the convert in SQL.  I have tried all the format in SQL that are of a decimal nature.  These all cause the type mismatch in Excel.  INT works, but I need the decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to use the AtomSvc file to get data from a SSRS report into Excel.  By opening Power, Select Get Data from Other Sources.  From the list that comes up select "Other Feeds" under Data Feeds.   In the Data Feed URL, you can browse and select the AtomSvc file. (Ideally keep the file in a location that is accessible to anyone that you intend on sharing the Excel file with.)

Return the data to Excel in a Pivot Table.   Refreshing the table will get the latest data from the SSRS report, via the details in the AtomSvc file.   This method avoids the Type Mismatch.

A limitation in this method, is that if new columns are added to the SSRS report, the new columns don't pull to the Excel Pivot table.   The connection has to be re-created. ... but it works, and when the spreadsheet is sent to the required users no data connection directly to SQL is required and access is controlled by permissions on the Report server.